# HTTPResponse as JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, httpresponse

I was trying to get an JSONObject from a HTTP response.

```
try
    {   
        GetMethod postMethod = new GetMethod();
        postMethod.setURI(new URI(url, true));
        postMethod.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        String resp=postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        org.json.JSONTokener tokener = new org.json.JSONTokener(resp);
        finalResult = new org.json.JSONArray(tokener);

        return finalResult;
    }
```

But I got a runtime warning as

> Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size. Using `getResponseBodyAsStream` instead is recommended.

Should I get the response as stream as suggested by the JVM ? If so, how could I parse the JSON from it ?

Comment: Just read the content to a `byte[]`, turn that `byte[]` into a `String` (depending on the encoding) and parse that `String` as JSON

Comment: I would hope that one of the several dozen JSON packages for Java can read directly from a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to send `jsonObjects` from server suppose (tomcat server)

For server side-

creating `jsonobjects`-

I have Called `toJson()` for creating `jsonobjects` this is the implementation-

```
final JSONObject arr = new JSONObject();

for (int i = 0; i < contactStatus.size(); i++) {
    ContactStatus contactObject = contactStatus.get(i);

    try {
        arr.put(String.valueOf(i), toJson(value1, value2,, value3));
    } catch (JSONException e) {

     catch block e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Here we serialize the stream to a String.
final String output = arr.toString();
response.setContentLength(output.length());
out.print(output);//out is object of servlet output stream.

public static Object toJsonForContact(String value1, boolean value2, double value3) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject contactObject = new JSONObject();
    contactObject.put("id", id);
    contactObject.put("status", value1);
    contactObject.put("distance", value2);
    contactObject.put("relation", value3);
    return contactObject;
}
```

so your `jsonobjects` are ready for sending we write these objects to `ServletoutputStream`.

in client side-

```
while ((ReadResponses = in.readLine()) != null) {
        Constants.Response_From_server = ReadResponses;

        if (Constants.Response_From_server.startsWith("{")) {
            ListOfContactStatus = new ArrayList<ContactStatus>();
            ContactStatus contactStatusObject;

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Constants.Response_From_server);

                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    contactStatusObject = new ContactStatus();

                    JSONObject json1 = json.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
                    System.out.println("" + json1.getString("id"));
                    System.out.println("" + json1.getBoolean("status"));
                    System.out.println("" + json1.getDouble("distance"));

                    contactStatusObject.setId(json1.getString("id"));
                    contactStatusObject.setStatus(json1.getBoolean("status"));
                    contactStatusObject.setDistance((float) json1.getDouble("distance"));
                    ListOfContactStatus.add(contactStatusObject);
                    System.out.println("HTTPTransport:sendMessage  Size of ListOfContactStatus" + ListOfContactStatus.size());
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Has your server been set up to inform clients how big its responses are? If not, your server is streaming the data, and it's technically impossible to tell how much buffer space is required to deal with the response, warranting a warning that something potentially dangerous is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily generate JSonObject usin Java EE 7. The sample code.

```
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new URI(url, true));
    JsonObject jsonObject=reader.readObject();
```

For details information go through to the link.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp003.htm#BABHAHIA